# sufficient permissions

Tags: boot

where do I find 'sufficient permissions" to run this program?  The executable ./synergys.exe could not be successfully started.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What doesn't have sufficient permissions?

Answer (score 2):

You have not given a lot of information, but I think I know what is happening.

In order to run certain programs, they need to be elevated so that they can have administrative access to your machine.

The easiest way to do this is to find the program, right click on it and choose `Run as Administrator`.

If you are running from command prompt, make sure that you do the previous step first on the command prompt, then anything that the command prompt runs will run as administrator by default.

Answer (score 1):

May be you have installed the 64-bit version on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: it suits as comment ,it cant be a answer